# Find if the given time between two times

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a code to check if the given time is between 2 passed in times. If the end time is `23:59` (i.e. 11:59 PM ) this works, but if it is `00:00`, my code fails.

Here is my sample code.

```js
const getStatus = (startTime, currentTime, EndTime) => {
  var currently = currentTime.split(":")[0] * 60 + currentTime.split(":")[1];
  var starting = startTime.split(":")[0] * 60 + startTime.split(":")[1];

  var ending = EndTime.split(":")[0] * 60 + EndTime.split(":")[1];

  return starting < currently < ending;
}

console.log(getStatus('06:00', "12:00", "18:00"));
console.log(getStatus('06:00', "12:00", "00:00"));
```

In reality, `12:00 PM` falls between `6:00 AM` and `12:00AM`, but my code returns false, since, `12:00AM` is coming as `00:00` as input from my system. Is there a direct way of doing it or should I replace `00:00` with `11:60` and do it?

Comment: Is `00:00` supposed to represent last midnight or this midnight? i.e. 1 minute before `00:01` or 1 minute after `23:59'`?

Comment: Good one @Nick, that's where even I was stuck. this is a store timing that runs from `6:00 AM` to `12:00 AM`, which I think should be `11:59 PM` as closing, but I can't touch the backend system.

Comment: So that sounds like it should be 1 minute after `23:59`. Why not use `23:59` in your code and change the test to `<=` instead of `<`?

Comment: You might need to just add an edge case if you can't change the "00:00" end time parameter value (from the backend), eg `endTime = endTime == "0:00" ? "11:59" : endTime` - or, more likely:  `ending = ending === 0 ? ending = 24*60 : ending;`

Comment: @Nick `00:00` is always the start of a day and as such always refers to last midnight. Next midnight would be `00:00` on the next day.

Comment: @feela correct - the issue (as described) is that `EndTime` parameter is being passed as `"00:00"` from the back end - as it's an *end time* then you would have to assume it means this midnight.

Comment: replace "00:00" with "11:60" - that would be *noon*  :)   as you're parsing the string, you could replace "00:00" with "24:00" and that would work (just for EndTime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an elegant solution but if your time end time is 00:00 (midnight) you can replace it with 24:00

```js
const normalizeTime = (time) => {
  return (time === '00:00') ?
    '24:00' : 
    time;
}

const getStatus = (startTime, currentTime, EndTime) => {
  EndTime = normalizeTime(EndTime);
  var currently = currentTime.split(":")[0] * 60 + currentTime.split(":")[1];
  var starting = startTime.split(":")[0] * 60 + startTime.split(":")[1];

  var ending = EndTime.split(":")[0] * 60 + EndTime.split(":")[1];

  return starting < currently < ending;
}

console.log(getStatus('06:00', "12:00", "18:00"));
console.log(getStatus('06:00', "12:00", "00:00"));
```

Comment: *Probably* only want to apply this to EndTime and *probably* only if it's exactly `"00:00"`, otherwise your start will be broken if you want it early morning.

Comment: yes thank you i edit my reply to only apply it only on endTime if it equal to 00:00

Answer (score 1):

Try this!

```js
// 3 statuses here
// 1 -> before
// 2 -> between
// 3 -> after


// I presume you mean all of these are date strings
const getStatus = (startTime, currentTime, endTime) => {
  const dateStart = new Date(dateStr1); // Covert to a date
  const dateTime = new Date(dateStr1);
  const dateEnd = new Date(dateStr1);

  const timestampStart = dateStart.getTime(); // Convert to a timestamp
  const timestampTime = dateTime.getTime(); // Convert to a timestamp
  const timestampEnd = dateEnd.getTime(); // Convert to a timestamp

  if (timestampTime < timestampStart) {
    return 'before'
  }

  if (timestampTime > timestampStart && timestampTime < timestampEnd) {
    return 'between'
  }

  return "after"
}
```

Comment: *I presume you mean all of these are date strings* - given the variable name is "xx**Time**" and the code does a `.split(":")[0]` - I think it would be safe to assume these are *time* strings and not full dates.

Answer (score 1):

For comparisons you might use the `Date` object:

```js
// 6 am today
opens = new Date();
opens.setHours(6, 0, 0, 0);  // setHours() accepts further arguments for minutes, seconds & milliseconds

// next midnight (00:00 tomorrow)
closes = new Date();
closes.setDate( closes.getDate() + 1 );
closes.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

current = new Date();

if(opens < current && current < closes) {
    alert("This store is open right now.");
}
```

Regarding ***"If the end time is 23:59 (i.e. 11:59 PM ) this works, but if it is 00:00, my code fails."***: If the end-time is lower than the start-time, you will **have to add a day**, since this time refers to somewhen tomorrow (even if it is the first second of the new day like in 00:00).